# Cleartool error: Unable to update view

Tags: linux, view, clearcase

I am using cleartool command in my linux machine. I am trying to merge a label `ONLINE_Dec_15` to `main` branch. I am using a view called `admin_view` with default config spec.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
```

The view has following permissions:

```
Owner: vobadmin           : rwx (all)
Group: ccusers          : rwx (all)
Other:                  : r-x (read)
```

The vob I am working on has following permissions set:

```
VOB ownership:
    owner vobadmin
    group ccusers
```

The file which has to get merged has following permissions:

```
Element Protection:
    User : vobadmin   : r--
    Group: ccusers  : r--
    Other:          : r--
```

I am able to perform merge with these permissions in other vobs. But I am getting this error in this case. What am I missing?

I am getting following error:

```
cleartool: Error: Unable to update view "admin_view": Permission denied.
cleartool: Error: Unable to check out "./app/test.java".
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/Unable%20to%20update%20view)

> - Ensure that your view was created with the correct permission's. Once again it is the Linux users' primary Group as defined when your create the Linux user.
> - Tip: Ensure the you use the correct umask setting when creating views
> - Ensure that when you created the viewstore, that you have set the correct user:group ownership

Try with a new view and see if the issue persists.

Make a comparison with other (working) views by comparing their:

```
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro <aview>
```